# group view disappear in expandable list view

Tags: android, expandablelistview, convertview

I have an Expandable list view that contain a list view when after a certain number of rows I add other custom view.
the problem is that when a try to expand the group for the 2nd time it disappear.

thank's in advance.
this is the code I wrote on the getChildView:

```
if(childPos == CurrGroup.MaxItems &&  CurrGroup.Competitors.size() > CurrGroup.MaxItems)
        {
            if(view == null)
            {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wizard_show_more_item, null, true);
                TextView leauge_title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.show_more_title);

                leauge_title.setText(UiUtils.getTerm(context, "SCORES_GAME_SHOW_MORE"));            

                view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
                {                   
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {                       
                        Intent TourAllCompetitorsIntent = new Intent(context, TournamentPromoAllCompetitors.class);

                        try 
                        {
                            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            ObjectOutputStream oos;                     
                            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
                            oos.writeObject(CurrGroup);
                            TourAllCompetitorsIntent.putExtra("Tournament", baos.toByteArray());
                            TourAllCompetitorsIntent.setAction(TournamentPromoAllCompetitors.ALL_COMPETITORS);

                            context.startActivity(TourAllCompetitorsIntent);
                        }
                        catch (IOException e) {}                        
                    }
                });
            }           
        }
        else
        {
            ChildeItemView holder = new ChildeItemView();
            if (view == null) 
            {
                CompObj CurrCompetitor = getChild(groupPos, childPos);

                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.competition_promo_child_item, viewGroup, false);

                holder.CompetitorIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_competitor_icon);
                holder.CompetitorText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_competitor);
                holder.SelectedImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_selected);
                holder.CompetitorID = CurrCompetitor.getID();

                view.setTag(holder);
                //view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.list_seperator);

                //holder.CompetitorIcon.setImageResource(UiUtils.getSportTypeRes(getGroup(groupPos).sid , true));
                holder.CompetitorText.setText(CurrCompetitor.getName());


                String CurrCompetitorLogoPath = CompetitorsLogosPath + String.valueOf(getChild(groupPos, childPos).getID()) + "_70x70.png";
                imageLoader.displayImage(CurrCompetitorLogoPath, holder.CompetitorIcon, options);

                view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {
                        ChildeItemView ViewHelper = (ChildeItemView)v.getTag();

                        if(ViewHelper != null)
                        {
                            // If Already Selected
                            if(SelectedCompetitors.contains(ViewHelper.CompetitorID))
                            {
                                SelectedCompetitors.remove(ViewHelper.CompetitorID);
                                ViewHelper.SelectedImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_non_selected);

                                TournamentActivity.updateNumOfSelectedCompetitors();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                SelectedCompetitors.add(ViewHelper.CompetitorID);
                                ViewHelper.SelectedImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_selected);

                                TournamentActivity.updateNumOfSelectedCompetitors();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                holder = (ChildeItemView) view.getTag();
            }
return view;
```